# Invalid Time Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a div that is populated using javascript. Once this is loaded I run another javascript code to get the date from the date e.g saturday. The issue i believe seems with the incorrect selector that displays the date.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#am-events-booking').text().length) {
      clearInterval(i);
      console.log('Text detected!');


      var day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
        weekday: 'long'
      }).format(
        new Date(
          document.querySelector('.am-event-sub-info > div')
          .innerHTML
          .split(' - ')[0] // only interested in the "February 27, 2021 11:30 am" part
        )
      );

      document.querySelector('.am-event-sub-info').innerHTML += '<div class="day">' + day + '</div>';


      console.log(
        new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
          weekday: 'long'
        }).format(
          new Date(
            document.querySelector('.am-event-sub-info > div')
            .innerHTML
            .split(' - ')[0] // only interested in the "February 27, 2021 11:30 am" part
          )
        )
      );




    } else {
      console.log('Waiting...');
    }
  }, 5000);
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-events-booking">


  <div id="am-event-22" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all;">
    <div class="am-event-data">

      <div class="am-event-info">
        <div class="am-event-sub-info">
          <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <div class="am-event-sub-info">
          <div><img src=""> Saturday, February 27th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get invalid time value

Comment: Your date input is invaid. Change to a valid date as input for `new Date()`. This is what you're providing as argument `new Date('Saturday, February 27th, 2021 11:30 am')` which is `Invalid Date`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that

```
document.querySelector('.am-event-sub-info > div')
```

also references div in

```
<div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>
```

Comment: @HugoHiasi, thanks. I also tried `$("#am-events-booking").find('am-event-sub-info:eq(1)').innerHTML.split(' - ')[0] ` but that doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: A working selector to get the TEXT (not innerHTML) from the div is:  console.log('data is->'+$('.am-event-sub-info > div:last').text()); The problem is that there is an additional &gt; at the beginning of the text.